# Bootstrap Tab collapse not working in nested tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Plugin used for tabcollapse : https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse.
**Expected result**: Both tabs should show tab collapse. 
**Current result**: Only tab 'A' shows tab collapse content while 'B' shows blank. 
**View it in mobile resolution**. 
Below is the sample code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.inner-tab').tabCollapse();
    })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-tabcollapse@0.2.6/bootstrap-tabcollapse.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" >
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs inner-tab" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" >
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home">
                    <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">
                    <p>Light Blue - is a next generation admin template based on the latest Metro design. There are few reasons we want to tell you, why we have created it:
                        We didn't like the darkness of most of admin templates, so we created this light one. We didn't like the high contrast of most of admin templates, so we created this unobtrusive one.
                        We searched for a solution of how to make widgets look like real widgets, so we decided that deep background - is what makes widgets look real.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Button with click event attached</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs inner-tab" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <li><a href="#home1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#profile1" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" >
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home1">
                    <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile1">
                    <p>Light Blue - is a next generation admin template based on the latest Metro design. There are few reasons we want to tell you, why we have created it:
                        We didn't like the darkness of most of admin templates, so we created this light one. We didn't like the high contrast of most of admin templates, so we created this unobtrusive one.
                        We searched for a solution of how to make widgets look like real widgets, so we decided that deep background - is what makes widgets look real.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Button with click event attached</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so lets make it here haha.

In my side it is showing but depending on its width.

Comment: It will show in tab 'A' but will show blank in tab 'B'